# how to kill a looper/runnable

Tags: android

I have an asynchronous job that is initiated from a button click listener.  It is a printing job so it will happen again and again throughout a day.  I want to make sure between print jobs that I am not leaking either threads or objects.    Is my looper.mylooper.quit() line all I need?

The listener code is:

```
    private final Button.OnClickListener cmdPrintOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        enableScreenForUse(false);
        setStatus("Saving any changes");
        saveButtonClicked();
        TwoInchZebraDocket newDocket  = new TwoInchZebraDocket(mRunDetailID, getContentResolver());  //could set this to final if we get problems -> see for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424924/how-can-i-pass-an-object-to-a-new-thread-generated-anonymously-in-a-button-liste/11425012?iemail=1#11425012
        setStatus("Creating docket for printing");
        PrintRunnable target = new PrintRunnable(newDocket, CheckoutActivity.this);
        new Thread(target).start();

      }
};
```

The runnable object code is:

```
    public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    printDocket();
    Looper.loop();
    Looper.myLooper().quit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think want you want is the AsyncTask. If "printDocket()" is updating your UI thread you will have to refer to the looper, which is incovenient.

Here is are the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Basically, do asynchronous thread work within doInBackground(), and UI updates within onPostExecute().

Comment: I tried both - but either way I have to have a looper.prepare() otherwise the bluetooth connection to the mobile printer fails.  Either way I still need to know whether or not there are any leaks.